# Ghost undefined #text element in javascript-generated html table

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing some code for a personal website as a side project.  I have some experience with html and javascript, but am encountering a weird bug I can't identify.  More specific context...

I have an XML file with some data in it, and want to generate an HTML table from that data in javascript (code shown below).  The table is generated as expected (woot) but right beneath the table the word "undefined" is printed.  I'm not sure where this could be coming from, since the html my javascript is generating is wrapped in "tbody" tags.  I am imagining it's some weird niche bug that someone more advanced could easily point out (I'm a little rusty with my javascript currently).

I've had some trouble converting my problem into a set of googleable keywords, which is why I figured I would post about it on here. I originally had my table hardcoded in HTML before I decided to refactor, and when everything was hardcoded, I didn't have this issue, so I imagine it was introduced by my refactoring.

My html code for the table...

```
<h2 class="centered-title">Ability Scores</h2>
<table id="ability_scores"></table>
```

My javascript code for generating the table...

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Main Functionality

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '../stats.xml', true);
xhr.timeout = 2000;
xhr.onload = function() { document.getElementById("ability_scores").innerHTML = generate_ability_score_table(this.responseXML); }
xhr.ontimeout = function(e) {};
xhr.send(null);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Helper Functions

// GENERATE ABILITY SCORE TABLE FUNCTION
// generates the ability score table html code
// given the xml file with the necessary information
function generate_ability_score_table(xml)
{
    // generate table header
    var table_header = generate_ability_score_table_header();

    // generate all the table entries
    var table_entries;
    var abilities = xml.getElementsByTagName("ability");
    var proficiency = parseFloat(xml.getElementsByTagName("proficiency")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    for (var i = 0; i < abilities.length; i++)
    {
        var table_entry = generate_ability_score_table_entry(abilities[i], proficiency);
        table_entries+= table_entry;
    }

    return `<tbody>${table_header}${table_entries}</tbody>`;
}

// GENERATE ABILITY SCORE TABLE HEADER FUNCTION
// generates the table header of the ability score table dumbly
function generate_ability_score_table_header()
{
    return "<tr><th>Ability</th><th>Score</th><th>Modifier</th><th>Save</th></tr>";
}

// GENERATE ABILITY SCORE TABLE ENTRY FUNCTION
// generates an entry to the ability score table
// corresponding to the ability passed into the function
function generate_ability_score_table_entry(ability, proficiency)
{
    var name = ability.children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var score = parseFloat(ability.children[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var is_proficient = parseFloat(ability.children[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var modifier = get_modifier(score); // <-- this function is just a wrapper for a switch statement
    var save = modifier + (is_proficient * proficiency);
    return `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${score}</td><td>${modifier}</td><td>${save}</td></tr>`;
}
```

*Edit*
Here is the relevant xml code:

```
<stats>
    <proficiency>3</proficiency>
    <abilityScores>
        <ability>
            <name>Strength</name>
            <score>8</score>
            <proficient>0</proficient>
        </ability>
        <ability>
            <name>Dexterity</name>
            <score>18</score>
            <proficient>1</proficient>
        </ability>
        <ability>
            <name>Constitution</name>
            <score>11</score>
            <proficient>0</proficient>
        </ability>
        <ability>
            <name>Intelligence</name>
            <score>10</score>
            <proficient>0</proficient>
        </ability>
        <ability>
            <name>Wisdom</name>
            <score>12</score>
            <proficient>0</proficient>
        </ability>
        <ability>
            <name>Charisma</name>
            <score>18</score>
            <proficient>1</proficient>
        </ability>
    </abilityScores>
</stats>
```

Here is a screenshot of my issue with the dev tools open so you can get a more full view of the problem:

[image]

Many thanks to the person who can help me track down this issue! :)

Comment: What are the back ticks for? Any kind of smart quotes should not be used.  I'm surprised the code runs at all.

Comment: @CharlesEF That's a template literal (aka "template string") - introduced with ES6, so available now with most browsers. MDN Docs - [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Correct @JoshuaT, I was aiming for a template literal

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Sorry I can't help with the actual problem.

Comment: What is the content of the variable `abilites` in `generate_ability_score_table()`, are you sure it isn't picking up an extra undefined variable in the array due to XML parsing?

Comment: @Snel23 - I just added my XML file (if that is at all useful) and am investigating further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, small mistake. For the variable `table_entries`, you don't initialize it to anything here:

```
// generate all the table entries
var table_entries;
```

So it's initial value is JS undefined. When you try to concatenate here:

```
table_entries+= table_entry;
```

For the first time in the loop, It joins the literal string "undefined" with the new first row for the ability, which leads to the actual text "undefined" showing up and a bunch of malformed HTML. The fix should simply be changing `var table_entries;` to `var table_entries = "";`

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thank you so much, sometimes the silly simple bugs are the hardest to track down.